# vcproj for an .exe without same-named .c?

Tags: msvc12, vcproj

Don't I need a `xxx.c` source within a `.vcproj` to make `xxx.exe`? (How) Could MSVC create a `.exe` without a same-named `.c` source file?

Consider [this `.vcproj`](https://github.com/FranklinChen/hugs98-plus-Sep2006/blob/master/src/winhugs/winhugs.vcproj): it's creating `winhugs.exe`. The proj requires `winhugs.h`, which is in that folder, various other `winhugs.xyz`, which are also there; but doesn't mention `winhugs.c`, neither is that anywhere in the repo.

`winhugs` is a windowsified veneer over `hugs`, and the proj does mention `hugs.c`, which is in the repo. But `hugs.c` is a Unix source, which compiles to `hugs.exe` using `make`/gcc, which I've already built successfully.

Is it possible the proj can also build from `hugs.exe` to produce `winhugs.exe`?

[I'm at MSVC v12.0, if that's relevant; but the sources all date back to 2006. That's why I have a `.vcproj`, which is an obsolete format.]

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be yes: that `.vcproj` will upgrade to a MSVC 12.0 `.vcxproj` (with lots of warnings) and then MSVC will build from it (with lots of warnings), to produce `winhugs.exe`.